# No matching FB_Init method found when it's in a block

Tags: plc, codesys

Running Ecostruxure machine expert which is CodeSys 3.5

I've got the following program structure:

Main: two  blocks, Init and Step0 linked by a transition.

In the vars of that main:

```
VAR
   My_Encoder : ENC_REF_M262;
   ...
END_VAR
```

So then in my `Init` block I have `My_Encoder.FB_Init(...)`

But the error message I get points to the variable declaration in `Main` which says "C0138 No Matching FB_Init method found fo this instantiation of ENC_REF_M262".

Answer (score 2):

Try using the [no_init](https://help.codesys.com/api-content/2/codesys/3.5.12.0/en/_cds_pragma_attribute_noinit/) attribute above your instantiated FB.

```
VAR
   { attribute 'no_init'}
   My_Encoder : ENC_REF_M262;
   ...
END_VAR
```

Whenever a function block is instantiated, a matching implementation of the FB_Init method is expected to occur (even inside a wrapping fb).

**N.B.** You will need to explicitly run the init code (`My_Encoder.fb_Init()`) somewhere if it has critical functionality

Answer (score 1):

Using the 'no_init' attribute will fix the compile error; however, (IMHO) this may not be the best solution. First, because you'll probably want to initialize the values and secondly because [calling FB_Init explicitly](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tc3_plc_intro/5094414603.html&id=), is strongly discouraged. Therefore I would like to explain why the error message occurs as well as giving some insight in how to solve the error.

The error is (AFAIK) due to either one of the two reason listed below.

1. When you declare and initialize a `POU` (e.g. an `FB` between the `VAR` and `END_VAR` keywords) and you directly initialize a value to one of it's inputs while this input is not included as `VAR_INPUT` of the `FB_Init` of the `POU`.

I'll clarify this with some code:

> ```
>  VAR
>     myFunctionBlock: FB_FunctionBlock(myInput:= 1);
>  END_VAR
> ```

.. Above we're initializing input "myInput" of object/instance "myFunctionBlock" with the value 1 and this requires that "myInput" is included in the FB_Init of POU "FB_FunctionBlock":

> ```
> METHOD FB_init : BOOL 
> VAR_INPUT     
>    bInitRetains : BOOL; 
>    bInCopyCode : BOOL;  
>    myInput : INT; // Include the input or else you'll get the error
> END_VAR
> ```

2. In the `VAR_INPUT`-block of an `FB_Init` you can include inputs of the `POU` to which the `FB_Init` belongs. When you do this your are required to initialize these inputs when you declare and initialize the `POU`. (this is probably the case in your example)

Again I'll clarify this with some code:

> ```
> METHOD FB_init : BOOL 
> VAR_INPUT     
>    bInitRetains : BOOL; 
>    bInCopyCode : BOOL;  
>    myInput : INT;
> END_VAR
> ```

.. Above input "myInput" is included in the FB_Init of POU "FB_FunctionBlock" and therefore when we create an object/instance of POU "FB_FunctionBlock" then we're required to initialize the input "myInput".

> ```
>  VAR
>     myFunctionBlock: FB_FunctionBlock(myInput:= 1); 
>     // Include "myInput:= 1" or else you'll get the error
>  END_VAR
> ```